# Problems in rendering Gantt Chart in angular 15 using d3

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, d3.js, gantt-chart

Trying to implement gantt chart using d3 in angular 15, the problem with the rendering. The data flow is correct, SVG and rectangles are created with my dummy data.

```
private data = [
    { task: 'Task 1', startTime: '2013-01-01', endTime: '2013-01-10' },
    { task: 'Task 2', startTime: '2013-01-05', endTime: '2013-01-15' },
  ];

private drawChart(): void {
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
    const width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    console.log('margin', margin);
    const svg = d3
      .select('#gantt-container')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    console.log('SVG created:', svg);

    svg
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', (d) => this.calculateXPosition(new Date(d.startTime), width))
      .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 30)
      .attr('width', (d) =>
        this.calculateWidth(new Date(d.startTime), new Date(d.endTime), width)
      )
      .attr('height', 20)
      .style('fill', 'steelblue');

    console.log('Rectangles created:', svg.selectAll('rect').nodes());
  }

  private calculateXPosition(date: Date, width: number): number {
    return (date.getTime() / this.getMaxMilliseconds()) * width;
  }

  private calculateWidth(
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    width: number
  ): number {
    return (
      ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / this.getMaxMilliseconds()) *
      width
    );
  }

  private getMaxMilliseconds(): number {
    const maxDate = d3.max(this.data, (d) => new Date(d.endTime) as Date);
    return maxDate ? maxDate.getTime() : 0;
  }
```

scaleTime().doamin() also not accepting the parameters that's why calculating scale and width manually.

Nothing is displayed on the page
Here's my template:

```
<div id="gantt-container"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
#gantt-container { width: 100%; height: 400px; }
```

Also tried the @viewChild but still no success. Please help!

Comment: Your code snippet does not provide enough information to help you.  How does `drawChart` get called?  Are you respecting Angular's component lifecycle?